# cannot use function from js in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, mathjs

i have a function to calculate area of polygon, and here's my function

```js
import {distance} from "mathjs"
function getArea(arrayCord) {
    let triangle =[]
    let area = 0.0
    let a =0.0
    let b =0.0
    let c =0.0
    let s =0.0
    for (let i = 0; i < arrayCord.length-2; i++) {
        a = distance(arrayCord[i],arrayCord[i+1])// p1-p2
        b = distance(arrayCord[i+1],arrayCord[i+2]) //p2 - p3
        c = distance(arrayCord[i],arrayCord[i+2]) //p3-p1
        s = (a+b+c)/2;
        triangle[i] = Math.sqrt(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c))
        area+= triangle[i]
    }
    return area;
}
```

when i copy the function into a typescript class and use it, i got this error that said

> Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'number | math.BigNumber' and 'number | math.BigNumber'

[image]

the function in my typescript was

```js
          const getArea = (arryy:(number|undefined)[][]) =>{
            let triangle =[]
            let area = 0.0
            let a:(number|BigNumber) =0.0
            let b:(number|BigNumber) =0.0
            let c:(number|BigNumber) =0.0
            let s:(number|BigNumber) =0.0
            for (let i = 0; i < arryy.length-2; i++) {
              a = distance(arryy[i],arryy[i+1])// p1-p2
              b = distance(arryy[i+1],arryy[i+2]) //p2 - p3
              c = distance(arryy[i],arryy[i+2]) //p3-p1
              s = (a+b+c)/2;
              triangle[i] = Math.sqrt(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c))
              area+= triangle[i]
            }
            return area;
        }
```

how to solve this problem so that i can use my function on my typescript class?

Comment: You have to convert the number to BigNumber before you add them. So do a type check, then add when both are guaranteed to be the same type.

Comment: how to do the conversion process?

Comment: To convert from and to  `BigNumber` see the [conversion section of the API](https://mathjs.org/docs/datatypes/bignumbers.html#conversion)

Comment: Why are you adding `BigNumber` to your TS snippets? You don't seem to be using `BigNumber` If you need run calculations on them, you can't use `+`, you have to call `math.add`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use regular arithmetic on `BigNumber`s.

Replace

```
s = (a+b+c)/2
```

with

```
s = math.divide(math.add(a, b, c), 2)
```

But you need to beware that `math.divide` returns `number | BigNumber | Fraction | Complex | Unit | Array | Matrix` so your `s` *may* need to have its type adjusted.

See:

- https://mathjs.org/docs/reference/functions/divide.html
- https://mathjs.org/docs/reference/functions/add.html

Answer (score -1):

`number` and `BigNumber` are seen as two data types, and Typescript doesn't know this addition operation is permitted. So in your case, `a` could be a `number` and `b` could be a `BigNumber`.

If you know for sure these can be added together, you can use `// @ts-ignore I'm sure this adds` on the line above the comment where error is shown.

Comment: Suggesting to ignore TS's warning makes me cringe. This should be a comment, you're not really answering the question but offering a workaround that assumes something that is likely not true (you can't add numbers and BigNumbers with `+`)

Comment: To each their own. If she finds it more useful to spend her time trying to get with the quirks of TS, however illogical or inconvenient for the sake of TS purity then your answer works great. If she might find this quirk a waste of her time, @ts-ignore is a complerely valid way for her to object to the way TS logic works.